# Calling object of a method in another method

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to use Instance Object below to call close() method. It gives an error: The name 'Instance' does not exist in the current context". Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong.

```
public class Trial
{
     public static void Initialize()
    {
        IWebDriver Instance = null;
        Instance = new FirefoxDriver();
        Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        Instance.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.com");
    }
     public static void Close()
     {
         Instance.Close();
     }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should spend some time reading some articles about variable scope. Here's one such article but there are many, many more.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

You originally declared `Instance` inside the `Initialize()` method. That means it can only be seen within the *scope* of that method. If you want to refer to it elsewhere, you have to declare it within the scope of where you want to have access to it. One way to do that in your code sample is to move the declaration of `Instance` into the `Trial` class. Once that is done, both the `Initialize()` and `Close()` methods are within it's (the `class`) scope so they both have access to the variable.

```
public class Trial
{
    static IWebDriver Instance = null;

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Instance = new FirefoxDriver();
        Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        Instance.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.com");
    }
    public static void Close()
    {
        Instance.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Instance` is "local" to `Initialize()` and so can't be seen by `Close()` - you might want to look at making `Instance` a member of the `Trial` class so that all methods can see it.